# How to set props dynamically in input field

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a dynamic input component using props

**This is App.js File**

```
<TextBox type="text" style="singIn" placeholder="hi there" />
<TextBox type="password" style="singUp" />
```

**This is TextBox.js File**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class TextBox extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    }

    render() {
        const {type, value, ...other} = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                <input type={type} value={value} {...other} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TextBox
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use state to set value dynamically, Instead of props.

Or

You can use state to set the value to props. So that if you change the state value automatically props value also will change.

Comment: please give me some example

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track!

In `TextBox`, what you can do in your `render()` method is to pass on **all** of the `props` to `<input>` using the [Object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) operator. This passes on all of the `props` as key value pairs. So, you can do:

```
<input {...this.props} />
```

That essentially does:

```
<input type={this props.type}
       value={this.props.value}
       placeholder={this props.placeholder}

       // and so on for every single key-value pair you have in props

       />
```

But, there *is* a slight problem. If you pass `style` as a prop, it must be ["a JavaScript object with camelCased properties"](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style). That is, you can't pass "signIn" or "signUp" (which are just strings) as a `style`. Perhaps what you meant to do is pass them as a `class` prop (meaning, set the CSS class of the input to "signIn" or "signUp").

Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/w7l1p94r4k) that demonstrates using the Object spread operator to pass all of the props on to the child `input`.

Comment: i am also try this `<input {...props} />` but not work

Comment: Try `<input {...this.props} />`

Comment: Click this link to show error
(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DDaYAv_S_h4k-7OvHmRbrsAEhb7V-3mD)

Comment: Can you use [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io) to try out your code? It is much easier for people to help you if they can see your code and see what errors may be occurring...

Comment: @BhavinTank From your code sandbox, it looks like you are able to pass on props through `TextBox` to `input`, using the Object spread operator. That looks good! So, when you use the similar approach to your code on your local machine, does it work?

Comment: Yes @Alvin Lee
I have one mistake in my first code, I have pass class name as a style.
`<TextBox type="text" style="singIn" placeholder="hi there" />`

Comment: @BhavinTank Passing in a string for the `style` prop will lead to an error in React (`The 'style' prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string.`). You will need to fix this if your code is going to work, as I described above.